# how to make additional color options added to default color Customizer save their value

Tags: theme-customizer

I've been able to add two other color options to the default Wordpress Color Customizer section using the following:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'understrap_hero_bgcolor', array(
    'default'           => '#ECEEEF',
    'type'              => 'color',
    'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
) );
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'understrap_hero_textcolor', array(
    'default'           => '#000',
    'type'              => 'color',
    'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
) );        
$wp_customize->add_control( 
    new WP_Customize_Color_Control( 
    $wp_customize, 
    'hero_bgcolor', 
    array(
        'label'      => __( 'Hero Background Color', 'understrap' ),
        'section'    => 'colors',
        'settings'   => 'understrap_hero_bgcolor',
    ) ) 
);
$wp_customize->add_control( 
    new WP_Customize_Color_Control( 
    $wp_customize, 
    'hero_textcolor', 
    array(
        'label'      => __( 'Hero Text Color', 'understrap' ),
        'section'    => 'colors',
        'settings'   => 'understrap_hero_textcolor',
    ) ) 
);
```

They load in the customizer fine, but they're not saving values in the back end, or for use in the front end using:

```
$hero_bgcolor = get_theme_mod( 'understrap_hero_bgcolor' );
$hero_textcolor = get_theme_mod( 'understrap_hero_textcolor' );
```

What do I need to do to allow extra color settings in the default Wordpress color customizer to save properly?

I'm using the [Understrap theme](https://understrap.com/).

Help appreciated.

Comment: Your code looks fine. This might help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203600/customizer-not-saving-options

Comment: @cjbj I increased memory to `512M` in `.htaccess` on Wampserver, but the issue remains.